# Shell script continue after failure

Tags: bash, shell

How do I write a shell script that continues execution even if a specific command failed, however I want to output as error later, I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --spec ./test/specs/login.test.js
rc=$?
echo "print here"
chown -R gitlab-runner /gpc_testes/
chown -R gitlab-runner /gpc_fontes/
exit $rc
```

However the script stops when the node modules command fails.

Comment: You could try `set +e` as the first line before calling wdio. This will make bash not exit on errors.

Comment: Exiting on failure isn't default behavior. Your script would need to be invoked with `bash -e yourscript` to have that effect with only the code given here (and if it isn't invoked in that way or some equivalent, `set +e` will have no effect).

Comment: If the `errexit` flag *isn't* being enabled through some code or invocation option not included in the question (on which point: *grumble* re: failing to include a [mcve]), I wonder if perhaps `wdio` is leaving the terminal in a bad state when it exits with errors, such that later `echo`s have no visible effect?

Comment: You didn't tell us, how you invoke the script. Without knowing this (see also the comments by Charles Duffy), your question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
command_that_would_fail || command_failed=1
# More code and even more
.
.
if [ ${command_failed:-0} -eq 1 ]
then
 echo "command_that_would_fail failed"
fi
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the underlying assumption in this answer is that the OP's code is somehow being called with `set -e` enabled, such that the `||` will mark the command as checked and thus avoid errexit behavior? If we *didn't* have errexit enabled (and neither their shebang nor their script turns it on), I'm unclear on how this would be any different.

Answer (score -4):

Suppose name of the script is test.sh.

While executing the scripting, execute it with below command

./test.sh 2>>error.log

Error due bad commands won't appear on terminal but will be stored in file error.log which can be referred afterwards.